# Specifying search direction in Excel VLOOKUP() function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

There are many great answers on Stack Overflow describing how to use Excel's `VLOOKUP()` function.  A few that I researched prior to asking this question are here:

- [Using VLOOKUP()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808932/using-vlookup)
- [Excel Vlookup Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16023472/excel-vlookup-function)
- [using lookup , vlookup formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649611/using-lookup-vlookup-formula)

It looks like `VLOOKUP()`, by default, returns the first matching entry in a table (i.e. "top-first" search).  I have a need to instead return the *last* entry in a table (i.e. "bottom-first" search) -- ***is there a way to specify search direction using the `VLOOKUP()` function or, barring that, an alternative function that works like `VLOOKUP()` but allows one to specify search direction?***

EDIT:
Here is a sample of my data.  I have network traffic where I am trying to calculate timestamp differences between packets with the same identifiers.

```
Packet ID  Timestamp (ms)
A          0.0
B          1.0
C          2.0
C          3.0
A          4.0
B          5.0
.          .
.          .
.          .
```

and I need to calculate the timestamp differences similar to below

```
Packet ID  Timestamp (ms) Timestamp Difference (ms, packet ID basis)
A          0.0            0.0
B          1.0            0.0
C          2.0            0.0
C          3.0            1.0 (i.e. "3.0 - 2.0")
A          4.0            4.0 (i.e. "4.0 - 0.0")
B          5.0            4.0 (i.e. "5.0 - 1.0")
C          6.0            3.0 (i.e. "6.0 - 3.0")
.          .              .
.          .              .
.          .              .
```

To accomplish this, I am trying to create a `VLOOKUP()` on `Packet ID` to find the timestamp of the directly previous packet with that same ID.

Comment: Speaking from a pure relational algebra point of view, it generally isn't a good thing that you have some lookup column with multiple matches.  What if, for example, the order of that data changes one day, such that the last (or first) match is no longer logically correct?  I vote for avoiding this situation altogether by having just one matching key in the lookup column.  But +1 to your question.

Comment: You could use `Index/Match` and on the `Match` nest a `Match` that lets you start later down the list.  Also, @TimBiegeleisen makes a good point. If you have so much duplicated data, there should (hopefully) be another variable you can use to narrow your search down.

Comment: Also, just [searching around](https://www.google.com/search?q=vlookup+get+last+entry) there's [this page](https://www.exceltip.com/excel-formula-and-function/vlookup-to-find-last-matching-value.html), and [this one](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2436-excel-vlookup-last-value.html), and [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/781992/how-to-get-vlookup-to-return-the-last-match). Do none of those help?

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen.  Normally I would agree for categorical data, however I am analyzing time-series data (network traffic with periodic packet identifiers) and need to calculate time offsets between packets of the same identifier.  I am using `VLOOKUP` to search for the directly previous packet of the same identifier and taking the difference between their timestamps.

Comment: @BruceWayne, [This link](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2436-excel-vlookup-last-value.html) from your comment gave me what I need.  If you add it as an answer, I will accept it; otherwise I will add it as an answer later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this page](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2436-excel-vlookup-last-value.html), you should be able to use:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(A2:A12=D2),B2:B12)
```

and to ignore zeroes you can use this CSE formula (enter with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>)

```
=LOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307,IF(A2:A12=D2,IF(ISNUMBER(B2:B12),B2:B12)))
```

(Adjusting ranges as necessary)

Comment: This is a great, general answer.  For my particular scenario, I edited the formula to `=LOOKUP(2, 1/($A$2:A(n-1)=A(n)), $B$2:B(n-1))` where `A(n)` is the cell containing the packet ID of the current row in the dataset, `A(n-1)` is the cell directly above it, and `B(n-1)` is the corresponding timestamp directly above the current row.

Comment: That's a clever way to handle it.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs - I agree! (Unfortunately I don't know if I'd be clever enough to come up with it).

Answer (score 2):

Why not create *your own* `VLOOKUP()` UDF?

```vb
Function VLOOKUP2(lookupVal, tblArray As Range, colIndex As Long)

    Dim r As Long
    r = tblArray.Find(What:=lookupVal, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    VLOOKUP2 = tblArray(r, colIndex)

End Function
```

*Disclaimer: The extent of my testing is what you see in the below image.*

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering, K.Davis.  While your solution does work, I marked @BruceWayne's answer "correct" because it solves the problem using pre-existing Excel functions.

Comment: @EricSchnipke - Keep this answer in mind in case you need to add more functionality or conditions as this is pretty easily expandable to more custom lookups.  Good thinking K.Davis :D

Answer (score 0):

As @tim says, it usually is best to use unique values as indices so that you don't have problems when it is sorted. If this is something that is not an index (e.g., a date) then this is fine.

I would use an array formula (hit ctrl, shft, enter to add the curly braces, instead of just enter):

```
{=INDEX(K34:K38,LARGE(IF(K34:K38="a",ROW(K34:K38),),1)-ROW(K34)+1)}
```

Here's the breakdown:

```
INDEX(<<target column range>>,

 #Compare all the recorded row numbers, and get the largest
 LARGE(

     #For each item in the column, check to see if it matches the 
     #search value
  IF(<<column range to search>> = <<value to search>>,
     #if it does, record its row number          
     ROW(<<column range to search>>),
  )
 )

 #since we are getting the absolute row number (not relative to the
 #target column, we need to calculate an offset
 -ROW(<<start item>>)

 #excel ranges start at 1 and not 0 so we have to correct the offset
 +1
)
```